# Why does Sherlock (BBC) use miles?

Tags: realism, sherlock

I've just started watching the BBC series *Sherlock* on Netflix. In the first 5 episodes, we've noticed that Sherlock and Watson always refer to long distances in miles rather than kilometers. It was my understanding that, since they are in the U.K., distances would be measured in kilometers. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96453/discussion-on-question-by-brettfromla-why-does-sherlock-bbc-use-miles).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The UK’s usage of the metric system is a mixed bag. Here’s a somewhat brief overview:

### Travel

- [Large distances](https://images.app.goo.gl/Znc6cjy588LpCQzS6) are measured in **miles**, with **yards** for [shorter](https://images.app.goo.gl/hdmkMwJC4fmn19UL8) ones
- Speed is **miles per hour**, or **mph**
- [Fuel](https://images.app.goo.gl/fkxPkWRpLN5ApgY5A) is purchased in **litres**
- [Fuel efficiency](https://www.honestjohn.co.uk/realmpg/dacia/sandero-2013) is measured in **miles per gallon** <sup>(1)</sup>, or **mpg**
- The space within a car will be given in **litres**

### Around the home

- [Weather](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=weather%20london) is almost always discussed in **Celsius**
- The sizes of rooms will be given in both **square foot** and **square metres**
- [Computer and TV screens](https://images.app.goo.gl/wXV2UyoJR3nTsD2A9) are given in diagonal **inches**
- Standard sizes of furniture (for example, [kitchen units](https://images.app.goo.gl/rek5TfkELBF66wmL7)) are measured in **millimetres**.
- Paper is **A sizes** (A4 being the most common), which are metric.
- Beds (well, [mattresses](https://www.bedandmattress.co.uk/size_guide)) are measured in **feet and inches**, and given names, including single (3’ x 6’3”), small double (4’ x6’3”) and Superking (6’ x 6’6”).
- People will mostly use **feet** and **inches** for their height. A few younger people may use **centimetres**.
- Depending on age people will use **stone** and **pounds** or **kilograms** for their weight

### Food

- When cooking people will use either **grams** or **ounces**, mostly depending on age
- All food legally has to be sold in **grams** or **millilitres**. However...

  - [Milk](https://images.app.goo.gl/6w3j9kUWANr8XXpd6) will be sold by the **pint**<sup>(2)</sup> (1, 2, 4 and 6 pint bottles) - but be labelled with the respective amount in millilitres too.
  - Beer is purchased by the **pint**
  - Wine is purchased in **75cl** (**750ml**) bottles
  - Some other miscellaneous products will be a weird number of **grams** or **millilitres** - especially products in glass bottles, like [vinegar](https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/products/261781314?sc_cmp=ppc*GHS%20-%20Grocery%20-%20New*PX%20%7C%20Shopping%20GSC%20%7C%20All%20Products%20%2B%20Tesco%20Brand*New:%20F%26D:%20Food%20Cupboard:%20Food%20Cupboard*PRODUCT_GROUP261781314*&gclsrc=aw.ds&ds_rl=1116019&ds_rl=1116016&ds_rl=1116019&gclid=CjwKCAjwmtDpBRAQEiwAC6lm47iOFj43MYhqPNjnk42y0UGOLj-8-xmoMRVt4XWzOz4i4z0mxZvcXhoCAS8QAvD_BwE).
  - [Steak](https://www.millerandcarter.co.uk/oursteak/our-steak-cuts) and burgers will be sold as a number of **ounces**
- Not exactly non-metric, but [eggs](https://images.app.goo.gl/QWZnuRDNW57GM4e76) are still sold by the **half dozen** or **dozen**. More recently it has been possible to buy packs of 10 or 15 eggs (but I’ve never seen a pack of 5).

### Miscellaneous

- [Land](https://www.cheffins.co.uk/rural/property-search.htm) is measured in **acres** or **hectares**
- Horse races are measured in **furlongs**
- Horses themselves are measured in **hands**
- Tools (Allen keys, drill bits) will often come in both metric and imperial sizes - very frustrating!
- [Desk fans](https://www.argos.co.uk/browse/appliances/fans-heaters-and-dehumidifiers/fans/c:29439/) come in 6, 9, 12 and 16 **inch** diameters normally.

---

- (1) - a gallon in the U.K. is 4.546 litres
- (2) - a pint in the U.K. is 20 fluid ounces, or 568ml.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96452/discussion-on-answer-by-tim-why-does-sherlock-bbc-use-miles).

Comment: If you disagree with the answer, please post a new one. If you want to suggest additions, post them in the chat link above or post your own answer.

Answer (score 22):

It's a little-known fact that the U.K. is actually one of the few - if not the only - place(s) in Europe that [still uses miles to measure distance](https://www.autotrader.com/car-news/newsflash-the-uk-uses-miles-per-hour-269875)! The U.K. does use some metric, but it's a bit of a mix, and distance is one of the areas where they're still on the imperial system.

Comment: Little known fact by who? Everyone in the UK knows this as does, I’m willing to bet, most people in Europe (as the source of a joke, if nothing else). I suspect what you mean by “little known” is most people in America, who are - as a general - famous for having little knowledge of the world outside their own country?

Comment: Americans would not even think to notice this as an 'issue', since they also use miles and it would (Sherlock using miles) would fit their world-view.